# Cannot access jump drives

Tags: usb-drive

To Whom It May Concern:

For two months now I have not been able to get to the photos and files on my jump drives when I need to use them for various reasons. At the same time this started I also lost the bar at the bottom of the page that contained my minimized software. When I minimize, the software is lost to me until I shut down and restart. As such, I am simply making the window smaller and hiding widows on the page behind other windows so as to not lose anything I'll need later.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,

Tom M.

Comment: I answered a similar question before: http://askubuntu.com/questions/180149/external-usb-drive/180987#180987

Comment: What are my best options for getting someone to walk though this with me in real time? I can't make heads or tails out of the instructions offered here--I do not speak the language. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what version you are on, but you should be able to cycle through open applications by pressing alt + tab. If that doesn't work, I'm thinking that your apps aren't minimized.

Also consider using workspaces to keep running applications organized, it can be accessed in a number of ways. The coolest way to bring them up is with expo, press super + w.

As far as jump drives, my guess is that they are set up on a format that doesn't like. There are lots of ways to figure this out, usually even when Ubuntu isn't "seeing" them. Try plugging one in, then from a terminal enter

lspci

This will give you a print out of every piece of everything connected to your pci bus. See if that lists anything that looks like your drive and go from there

Comment: This bit of advice (alt+tab) is helpful. Thanks. That's my kind of language.

Comment: What do you mean by "...then from a terminal enter Ispci"? What is a terminal? Thanks.

Comment: terminal is an application to enter commands at the command line.

Comment: sorry, i'm new to this forum, apparently pressing return posts comment. Anyway, bring up your dash, and type in 'terminal', you should see one or more applications pop up. Select one of them, and it will take you to a command line. the command is 'lspci', lowercase L, its shorthand for "give me a list of what's on my pci"

Comment: I've just gone from toddler back to infantile: What does "bring up your dash" mean? How would I do that? What page or place to I need to go to to do what you've said? See, I need someone on the phone walking me through this process. I think I'll just give up and go back to Windows for dummies.