# AMD Unsupported Hardware now a blank but not black screen not broken pipes 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I cannot see any programs but the screen has the normal background - unable to do anything if I want to get out control alt delete and then I can exit - read most of the articles but I am unable to change anything. This all happened after I followed a command line that said it would get rid of the AMD unsupported hardware - is there a way of just breaking in?

Comment: From the "question" it is not clear what actually happen. I recommend you to ask more clear and exact, what you did enter on command line and what happen afterwards. Otherwise, nobody can help you..

Comment: I agree, it is no clear what you did. If you want to get to a terminal, just press Ctrl + Alt + F1 and enter you login info.

Comment: I tried  Ctr-Alt-F1 and it would not accept my login or password

Comment: I am presently looking for the code I put into the terminal DRIVER=/usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
echo "Come on AMD!"
for token in $DRIVER; do
    echo "Removing AMD logo from "$token
    for x in $(objdump -d $DRIVER|awk '/call/&&/EnableLogo/{print "\\x"$2"\\x"$3"\\x"$4"\\x"$5"\\x"$6}'); do
        sed -i "s/$x/\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90/g" $DRIVER
    done
done
echo "Reboot computer to finish"

Comment: so I wonder why did you do that... until you run something, you shoud understand, what you are doing, otherwise you risking the need of re-installation.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the console (Ctrl+alt+F1) and backup your documents. ([External USB Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180149/external-usb-drive))

Reinstall

and you are saved.

And next time don't do that...

---

OR
once you are in console, try to

create a new user

login as a new user - most probably new profile will take a new setup.

Comment: Thank you but what can you expect from old people - just straight ahead thanks again